# Error: no matching package named 'pallet-contracts-rpc' found

Tags: rpc, pallet-contracts

I am trying to add the pallet-contracts-rpc dependency but keep getting this error.

'''
error: no matching package named `pallet-contracts-rpc` found
location searched: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.32
required by package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/kaioh/DeSign-/node)`
'''

I have also tried comparing with substrate contracts node template https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/tree/v0.23.0 and I see its not implemented in their node/cargo.toml file. I am using polkadot version 0.9.32.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was [removed in #12358](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12358), You no longer need to add the RPCs. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/bin/node/runtime) as an example.

> ### Porting Guide
>
> The high level contracts API in polkadot.js already uses `state_call` so upgrading to the latest version here is enough. If you are using api.rpc.contracts directly you need to switch to api.call.contractsApi.